# Feed Me Issue (yii\base\ErrorException)

Tags: plugin-feedme

I’ve got a ton of data to import into Craft. So I did a quick test installation to make sure it was feasible. Imported multiple CSVs into Craft using Feed Me, without an issue.

Then, created a new installation. The users were in a JSON file, imported that via Feed Me. Again, no problems. There were a couple of changes to make so I ran the feed a couple of times to tweak things. But no problems.

Then, went to import the first content CSV and on the feed-me/feeds/map/8 page ran into the following PHP error: "PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException | Trying to access array offset on value of type null".

I’ve tried cutting the CSV down to one row, I’ve tried the old test file I used. Same error, every time.

If I go back and rerun the user import feed it runs no problem.

Now, I do have the test installation with all of the content in it. I could just grab that and import it into the database proper, but I’m reluctant to do that because there’ll be associations in there I don’t understand, plus the point of importing the users first was to be able to associate the content with the users.

Edit: I’ve tried stripping the CSV down to a single column and 10 rows. I get the same error.

Any advice gratefully received.

Full error message as follows:

````
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(77): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Trying to acces...', '/Users/btmm/Dro...', 80)
#1 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/feed-me/src/web/twig/variables/FeedMeVariable.php(80): craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Trying to acces...', '/Users/btmm/Dro...', 80, Array)
#2 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php(1507): craft\feedme\web\twig\variables\FeedMeVariable->getSelectOptions(Array, 'name', 'id', false)
#3 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Template.php(106): twig_get_attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig\Source), Object(craft\feedme\web\twig\variables\FeedMeVariable), 'getSelectOption...', Array, 'method', false, false)
#4 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/88/8818d15babf1b4e2b369090cb7e2ed43542ae59b1fc3e8deba8840602e64ead1.php(150): craft\helpers\Template::attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig\Source), Object(craft\feedme\web\twig\variables\FeedMeVariable), 'getSelectOption...', Array, 'method')
#5 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_e1d51ed59a64e0d7d3187dcc1e6937f09dfcdd76676f3d86778ce04bb3887f11->block_extraSettings(Array, Array)
#6 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/33/330aaa3c600c1d31528249e314d7246dcfb0312eb4dc3fa7529f44f34428b83f.php(237): Twig\Template->displayBlock('extraSettings', Array, Array)
#7 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_b51ad463a0ecfffd1eaa3cc609fb4edd1eefa83a769fed58bbb0bd5188e31e3e->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#8 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#9 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/88/8818d15babf1b4e2b369090cb7e2ed43542ae59b1fc3e8deba8840602e64ead1.php(72): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#10 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_e1d51ed59a64e0d7d3187dcc1e6937f09dfcdd76676f3d86778ce04bb3887f11->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#11 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#12 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/46/46438ba2927156c11137c4a8c3ce9caf7349a7b29ef28347199c7b8db0d7e2d4.php(246): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#13 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_7f530ade0882b1f23387ade03f8596c939e175920bab34f570a294ac09bafe3e->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#14 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#15 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/da/da7527cf1fc1f8438629f7ea8d47d0b3c217d732487de361513a26df06aa8270.php(169): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#16 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_0abbf789d13562946371aa789cbff899ef34f47fd8a04b2ef9f0af4ac94c3acd->block_content(Array, Array)
#17 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/dc/dc50eafb26acfbc4fe5c821f87893ac60283f962a10493adb9a0699e4f2ca7cf.php(497): Twig\Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#18 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_36d5701a2fd85767262f79865f74097dcdf5a467e6b49d6710dcd3f3839c04e8->block_main(Array, Array)
#19 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/dc/dc50eafb26acfbc4fe5c821f87893ac60283f962a10493adb9a0699e4f2ca7cf.php(316): Twig\Template->displayBlock('main', Array, Array)
#20 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_36d5701a2fd85767262f79865f74097dcdf5a467e6b49d6710dcd3f3839c04e8->block_body(Array, Array)
#21 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/ed/ed5833dea75594e5aa2e80cb507f162a4479600167cb6c619fc463cadd629225.php(90): Twig\Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#22 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_20cfa3d02f796c5087758c31bc57fabd958c1b29561479d108c9698a169b05fd->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#23 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#24 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/e4/e4cbdcf643e11ae9f873ab1b56362b19f641544f6a7142d27deb13ebcbd2b0c6.php(56): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#25 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_763db36257acb2fba7a4b356f3e297426cf9c6df2cec22a281baf27531b234c6->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#26 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#27 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/dc/dc50eafb26acfbc4fe5c821f87893ac60283f962a10493adb9a0699e4f2ca7cf.php(158): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#28 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_36d5701a2fd85767262f79865f74097dcdf5a467e6b49d6710dcd3f3839c04e8->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#29 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#30 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/23/23482e7db7070131833850fe29e92c66ebbaf4391b58dc04f0ee541786db8e81.php(57): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#31 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_5e415ac6d0004c135965faaf878d56e23b3b7607da43f950b808d6cf6915d9d8->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#32 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#33 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/da/da7527cf1fc1f8438629f7ea8d47d0b3c217d732487de361513a26df06aa8270.php(79): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#34 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_0abbf789d13562946371aa789cbff899ef34f47fd8a04b2ef9f0af4ac94c3acd->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#35 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#36 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#37 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
#38 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
#39 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(390): Twig\Environment->render('feed-me/feeds/_...', Array)
#40 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(451): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('feed-me/feeds/_...', Array)
#41 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(257): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('feed-me/feeds/_...', Array, 'cp')
#42 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/feed-me/src/controllers/FeedsController.php(104): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('feed-me/feeds/_...', Array)
#43 [internal function]: craft\feedme\controllers\FeedsController->actionMapFeed('8', NULL)
#44 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#46 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('map-feed', Array)
#47 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): craft\web\Controller->runAction('map-feed', Array)
#48 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction('feed-me/feeds/m...', Array)
#49 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): craft\web\Application->runAction('feed-me/feeds/m...', Array)
#50 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(259): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#51 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#52 /Users/btmm/Dropbox/My Mac (MacBook-Pro.lan)/Documents/client_sites/wdd_dev/web/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#53 {main}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK… entirely my own stupid fault.

In an effort to simplify my data structure I’d merged two sections into one. However, I’d forgotten that I’d set one of those types of entry as a field in the section I was trying to import content into. Feed Me was obviously trying to find a related entry that no longer existed. As soon as I corrected my mistake it worked fine.

You live and learn I guess